# SWIG: No module name specified using %module or -module

Tags: c++, swig

I am using SWIG to generate some language bindings to some C++ code. I am getting this warning at the console:

> No module name specified using %module or -module

The warning is self explanatory, but is it something I should worry about?

Comment: Is that a really a warning not an error? The module name is used to import the generated module into the target language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is something to worry about.  It is an error not a warning and the generated wrapper file was not created (at least not with the SWIG 2.0.8 version I tested with).  Simply add `%module modulename` to the top of your SWIG `.i` file.